# Azure Cosmos DB partitioning and Indexing of Data in SQL API using PATH

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am collecting IoT data to Azure cosmos DB. I know COSOMOS DB SQL API is auto indexed by Path. I have around 150 sensors in each document, and most of sql queries are of

**DeviceId is already Partition Key**

> Select c.sensorVariable  From c where c.DeviceId = 'dev1' AND c.time= date1'
>
> { "DeviceId" : 'dev1' , "time" : 123333 , "sensor1" : 20 , "sensor2" : 40}

I will Fetch the various sensors data but all my queries are depend on depend on deviceId and time( which is in Unix Timestamp )

Is it possible to index data on deviceID and time and exclude other keys, which are also in the same path / .

And for collection by default

```
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Spatial",
                "dataType": "Point"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

It comes with this I feel as for DataType String shouldn't it be having Hash kind indexing rather than Range? And what is this **Precision : -1**

In Azure cosmos DB doc examples I have seen precision as 3 for string, I did not understood why ?

If I have 100 devices and putting data every second level what type of indexing is better ?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Partially Jay , but it helped to gain knowledge

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to index data on deviceID and time and exclude other
> keys , which are also in the same path

Yes. You could custom your index policy by `IncludedPaths` and `ExcludedPaths`.

Such as :

```
var excluded = new DocumentCollection { Id = "excludedPathCollection" };
excluded.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IncludedPath { Path = "/*" });
excluded.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath { Path = "/nonIndexedContent/*" });

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("db"), excluded);
```

Please refer to more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#changes-to-the-indexing-policy-specification).

> what is this Precision : -1
>
> In Azure cosmos DB doc examples I have seen precision as 3 for string, I did not understood why ?

Based on [Index data types, kinds, and precisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#index-data-types-kinds-and-precisions):

For a Hash index, this varies from 1 to 8 for both strings and numbers. The default is 3. For a Range index, this value can be -1 (maximum precision). It can vary from between 1 and 100 (maximum precision) for string or number values.

You could focus on this [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#index-precision) to make your choices.

> If i have 100 devices and putting data every second level what type of
> indexing is better ?

It's hard to say which index mode is the best choice. It should be considered with consistency level and your requirements for read and write performance. You could refer to this [paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#database-indexing-modes-a-idindexing-modesa).

Comment: Thanks for the reply . One more thing i observed is 
{ "datapoint1" : 23 , "datapoint2" : 20 , "datapoint3" : 45 } like i have 150 sensors 
{  "keyDataPoint" : 22 , "Data" : { "datapoin1" , "datapoint2" .... } } 
if i keep the data in above format and index data to only one level , that will improve performance.

Comment: @AmjathKhan Thank you for your sharing. So, any further questions?

Comment: I will test it as i have shared . Thank you , you are so much help for me.

Comment: @AmjathKhan Hi,any progress now? Does my answer helps you?